# Where can one find a list of all vendor-prefix CSS properties/extensions?

Tags: css, cross-browser, vendor-prefix

I frequently see new vendor-specific properties being used, what prompted this question was seeing `-moz-appearance:button;` somewhere (makes the element look like a button).

**Where can I find a list of all these extensions (vendor-prefix rules)?**

[Mozilla has one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS_Reference/Mozilla_Extensions), [Opera has one](http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/opera9/css/index.dml), there's an ["unofficial" one for webkit](http://qooxdoo.org/documentation/general/webkit_css_styles) (tho it doesn't explain the properties).  I had no luck for IE.  If there's not one all in one place, an *official, comprehensive* list for IE and webkit would do.

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/vendor-specific-properties/

Answer (score 4):

This one is great:

http://peter.sh/experiments/vendor-prefixed-css-property-overview/

Sitepoint also has a decent reference:

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/vendorspecific

Comment: The vendor prefix for the [KTHML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KHTML) engine, obviously. :P WebKit is based on KHTML.

Comment: There was a note at the bottom of the page that mentioned `-apple-` and `-khtml-`.

Comment: Please note that WebKit supports all these properties using the "-apple-" and "-khtml-" prefixes as well.

Comment: Peter's site is not complete. For instance it does not list `box-shadow` at the current time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use tools like [pleeease.io](http://pleeease.io/play/) where you can input your generic css and in return you can get css that most browsers will support:

**Input**

```
a {
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 10px;
  column-fill: auto;
}
```

**Output**

```
a {
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
     -moz-column-count: 3;
          column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
     -moz-column-gap: 10px;
          column-gap: 10px;
  -webkit-column-fill: auto;
     -moz-column-fill: auto;
          column-fill: auto;
}
```